# OPenXML with PowerPoint - arbitrarily splits up a hyperlink when enumerating links of a slide

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

The issue I am having is the code below will return a single hyperlink arbitrarily split up as multiple links vs. being a single hyperlink with its associated text.

For example, the hyperlink text is "Public: Download M365 T2T Migration (pdf)" and its URL points to a public website at https://download.microsoft.com/download/b/a/1/ba19dfe7-96e2-4983-8783-4dcff9cebe7b/microsoft-365-tenant-to-tenant-migration.pdf.

However, the code will return the hyperlink text is "Public: Download M365 T2T Migration (" yet the URL is accurate, i.e., it truncated the hyperlink text. In the next loop, it will return the text "pdf" again with the right URL. Finally, it will loop again and return the text ")" but again with the right URL.

I cannot find a pattern why this happens, but I need to resolve it.

**CODE**

```
foreach (Drawing.HyperlinkType link in links)
{
    // Iterate through all the external relationships in the slide part. 
    foreach (HyperlinkRelationship relation in part.HyperlinkRelationships)
    {
        // If the relationship ID matches the link ID…
        if (relation.Id.Equals(link.Id))
        {
            HyperLinks data = new HyperLinks(((DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlCompositeElement)link.Parent.Parent).InnerText, relation.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
            ret.Add(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just duplicated it by adding the offending hyperlink to a blank PPTX. I spell checked pdf and it suggested PDF which I saved and then it works. This doesn't help me as to why it is splitting hyperlinks across a single link of text; rather, it just is more info.